# If $\lim \int f_n\, d\mu = 0$ then $\lim \int f_n^a \,d\mu = 0$

Tags: measure-theory

I am trying to prove that if $f_n: [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is a sequence of nonnegative integrable functions, is bounded above, so $|f_n(x)| \leq M$, and if $$\lim \int f_n\, d\mu = 0$$ then for $a\in(0,\infty)$ we have that $$\lim \int f_n^a\, d\mu = 0.$$ Here is my thought: Because $f_n$ is bounded above by $M$, then $f_n^a$ is bounded above by $M^a$. Thus, $$f_n^a \leq M^{a-1}f_n.$$ Thus, by monotonicity, we have that $$\lim \int f_n^a \, d\mu \leq \lim \int M^{a-1} f_n\, d\mu = M^{a-1} \lim \int f_n \, d\mu = 0.$$ Because $f_n$ is nonnegative, it follows that $\lim \int f_n^a \, d\mu = 0.$

Is this correct?

Comment: What are the $f_n?$ They just pop up out of nowhere.

Comment: sorry, i was careless with inputting this. let me edit the op.

Comment: What is $\mu?$ And you really should write $\int_0^1$

Comment: This is how the problem is stated in the book. Here we use the Lebesgue integral, thus the $d\mu$.

Comment: Yes, but MSE is wide open to the world and is not restricted to just users of your book. So we like to clear things up a bit.

Comment: Absolutely, however, is the use of $d\mu$ for the Lebesgue integral not customary?

Comment: There's no one universal notation. In fact $d\mu$ often is used for a general measure. Often Lebesgue measure is denoted $dm,$ sometimes $d\lambda,$ and quite often just good ole $dx$ a la calculus.

Comment: Aside from notation, what is the context? Do you know the dominated convergence theorem? Holder? The fact that some subsequence $f_{n_k} \to 0$ a.e.?

Comment: I know the dominated convergence theorem, but not the other. We don't know that some subsequence goes to zero a.e., no.

Comment: Yup seems perfectly fine even for arbitrary nonnegative measures

Answer (score 1):

Your proof works for $\alpha \ge 1,$ but fails for $\alpha < 1.$ For example, if $f_n(x) = x^n,$ then $f_n(x) \le 1$ on $[0,1]$ for all $n.$ But $(f_n(x))^{1/2} \le 1^{1/2-1}f_n(x)$ fails.

However, Holder's inequality gives a simple proof for such $\alpha$:

$$\int_0^1 f_n^\alpha = \int_0^1 f_n^\alpha \cdot 1 \le \left (\int_0^1 (f_n^\alpha)^{1/\alpha}\right )^\alpha \left(\int_0^1 1^{1/(1-\alpha)}\right )^{1-\alpha} = \left ( \int_0^1 f_n \right )^\alpha\cdot 1 \to 0.$$